# Postgresql i have to return 0

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make one postgreSQL 9.3 query.The problem is here i have to count all cleaners rated below 4 rating.Here is my query

```
SELECT count(ratings.score) as below, avg(ratings.score) as avg_rating, cleaners.first_name, cleaners.last_name, cleaners.id, cleaners.created_at
FROM "cleaners"
LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.cleaner_id = cleaners.id
GROUP BY cleaners.first_name, cleaners.last_name, cleaners.id, cleaners.created_at
```

here is the following result:

```
{
  "HTTP_CODE": 200,
  "cleaners": [
    {
      "id": 29,
      "rating_below_3_stars": 1,
      "avg_rating": "5.0",
      "first_name": "asen",
      "last_name": "asenov"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "rating_below_3_stars": 2,
      "avg_rating": "2.5",
      "first_name": "Simepl",
      "last_name": "cleaner"
    }
  ]
}
```

The cleaner with id "29" his rating_below_3_stars have to e set to 0

What i want is:

```
{
  "HTTP_CODE": 200,
  "cleaners": [
    {
      "id": 29,
      "rating_below_3_stars": 0,
      "avg_rating": "5.0",
      "first_name": "asen",
      "last_name": "asenov"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "rating_below_3_stars": 2,
      "avg_rating": "2.5",
      "first_name": "Simepl",
      "last_name": "cleaner"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. please provide example of the current result and example of the desired result.

Comment: the result does not fit with the query. the query only selects ratings below 4, how do you achive an average of 5?

Comment: How can the result be a JSON document if your query isn't using any JSON function?

Comment: its fixed if you need more information please write

Comment: @john don't get it, if i select only rows with `ratings.score <= 3`how do you calculate an `avg(ratings.score)`of 5.0?

Comment: i just render the result

Comment: @user3696668   please provide example of the current result and example of the desired result.

Comment: without where clause is this result. my bad

Comment: @user3696668 where is `count(ratings.score) as below` in your result?

Comment: @John i assumed its called `rating_below_3_stars`

Comment: @ A ツ I figure that, it's just clear that what he shows isn't the result of the query. It's hard to solve a problem when the data presented might be false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you count only the ratings below 4

```
SELECT sum(case when ratings.score<=3 then 1 else null end) as below,
       avg(ratings.score) as avg_rating,
       cleaners.first_name, cleaners.last_name, cleaners.id,
       cleaners.created_at
FROM "cleaners"
LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.cleaner_id = cleaners.id
GROUP BY cleaners.first_name, cleaners.last_name, cleaners.id, cleaners.created_at
```

Comment: It works i cannot give + because of my rating :).Thank you